# tsocks doesn't redirect connection

Tags: slackware, tor, tsocks

After installing tsocks using slackbuilds I made /etc/tsocks.conf by the parameters for using tor.

```
server = 127.0.0.1
server_port = 9050
server_type = 5
```

Then I tried `tsocks firefox` to check it. But When I checked my IP (by whatismyipaddress.com and google) it was the same as I didn't use tor/tsocks.

another strength is that when I run `tsocks on` and then `tsocks show` I get the output: `LD_PRELOAD=""`, Which I think seems not set the libtsocks.so library to `LD_RELOAD`! Is this incorrect?

> I need tsocks for redirecting the connection of other applications
>   than firefox like wget and mininube.

How can I get tsocks to redirect connection through tor?

Comment: firefox supports SOCKS5 natively, no use for `tsocks` there.

Comment: I know. I used firefox to check my ip change.

Comment: Use something else like wget. Firefox is likely not to use the network APIs that `tsocks` hijacks directly but via shared libraries.

Comment: Note that `tsocks` won't anonymise fully since in most cases DNS resolution won't go through it. `socksify` from `dante` may work better in that regard.

Comment: I checked minitube too. When tsocks used to open minitube, It got err403 that was because of internet filtering.

Answer (score 1):

I have set the `LD_PRELOAD` manually to `libtsocks.so` and worked good, I think this may be a bug.

```
export LD_PRELOAD='libtsocks.so'
```